# Report Custom Summary Field

Tags: reporting

Is there any way to add condition to custom summary field?
What I want to do is get the total number of sale on each individual but I want to have another column which shows sales on certain type of product( excluding certain type of products ).

Data structure

Data structure

```
Name             Sales    Sales(on New Product)  status
Jone Done        $1000              $900
---Product A      $100                            not new
---Product B      $100                            not new
---Product C      $900                             new

Micheal Thomas    $500               $100
---Product A      $400                            not new
---Product C      $100                              new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your sObjects arranged in a Master-Detail relationship so you can use Roll-Up Summary Fields to get the `Total Sales` as in your example.

And you can create a custom Field (picklist, text, `Formula`) to hold a Product's `Status`, and then you can display that `Status` field on the Product-Related-List of the Parent.

But to show them together all nice-like requires a custom Visualforce Page to be embedded in the Standard Layout of the Parent.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I can embedded the report into the visual force page.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the "matrix" reports? It's an option next to "Summary" reports...

You can even combine it with "buckets" in the report if you don't have a straghtforward "is new / is not new" field on the product...

[image]

Comment: Thanks but matrix has limitation of displaying 2 levels deep which might not be flexible enough in the long run.

Comment: Happened once for me to date and I've cheated by building a "Name + email + city" formula ;) No worries, stuff like that rarely has 1 best answer and some sysadmins can't waste time learning Apex & VF for example.